# get all child nodes from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json:

```
    var source=[{'k':'01'},
                {'k':'02', 'children': [
                    {'k':'05'},
                    {'k':'06', 'children': [
                        {'k':'ABC'},
                        {'k':'PQR'}
                    ]},
                    {'k':'07'}
                ]},
                {'k':'03'}];
```

I want to be able to specify a value for k and get back all of the children (and grandchildren and great-grandchildren, etc.).

For instance if I provide `'02'`, I want to receive

```
            [
              {'k':'05'},
              {'k':'06'},
              {'k':'ABC'},
              {'k':'PQR'},  
              {'k':'07'}
            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
function mergeChildren(sources) {
  var children = [];
  for (var index in sources) {
    var source = sources[index];
    children.push({k: source.k});
    if (source.children) {
      children = children.concat(mergeChildren(source.children))
    }
  }
  return children;
}

function findChildrenForK(sources, k) {
  for (var index in sources) {
    var source = sources[index];
    if (source.k === k) {
       if (source.children) {
         return mergeChildren(source.children);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

`findChildrenForK` scans through an array of objects, `sources`, and matches their property `k` to the `k` supplied to the function. If a matching object is found, we call `mergeChildren` on that object's `children` property.

`mergeChildren` iterates through the array of objects given to it, and pushes each key into an array, called `children`. If any objects themselves have children, we concatenate them to our `children` accumulator by calling `mergeChildren` recursively and using the [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function.

See the script in action with your sample data in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naa46dj8/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var getChildren(key) {
  var x = source.filter(function(s){
     return s.k == key;
  });

  if( x.length && typeof x[0].children !== 'undefined') {
   return x[0].children;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer. So, i can check it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through your array matching the user input and then check if an specific element has the property you are looking for or not. Try this way,

```
var input = '02';

for(var index in source){
    if(source[index].k == input){
        if(source[index].hasOwnProperty('children')){
            console.log(source[index]); 
        }
    }
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/7bowkujx/)

Comment: your code is working good but it is showing only children not grandchildren

Comment: can you do it for this json 
`var source=[{'k':'01'} , {'k':'02','children':[{'k':'05'},{'k':'06', 'children':[{'k':'ABC'},{'K':'PQR'}]},{'k':'07'}]}, {'k':'03'}];`  
Because it's not showing for grand children

Comment: in that case you need recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var source = [{ 'k': '01' }, { 'k': '02', 'children': [{ 'k': '05' }, { 'k': '06' }, { 'k': '07' }] }, { 'k': '03' }];
            $.each(source, function (i, item) {
                if (item.k == "02")
                {
                    var list = item.children;
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: it's not returning grandchildren :( Otherwise it's working good

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function getChildren(source, parentId) {
    return $.grep(source, function(parent) {
        // get only parents with matched id
        return parent.k === parentId;
    }).reduce(function(children, parent) {
        // sum all children into one array
        return children.concat(parent.children || []);
    }, []);
}
```